# Rails test database not properly prepared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have strange problem with properly preparing test database in Rails3.

In schema.rb I have:

```
create_table "sites", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "ldap_dn",     :null => false
  t.string   "address"
  t.string   "phone"
  t.string   "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
end
```

then in one of my migrations I have:

```
change_column :sites, :id, :string, :limit => 255, :primary_key => true
```

Now, in **development** database after `rake db:migrate` I have

```
id VARCHAR(255) PK
```

**BUT in test database** after `rake db:test:prepare` I have

```
id INT(11) PK AI
```

In the log file (`test.log`) I can see all migrations are executed.

I use:

- rails 3.2.13
- mysql for both dev and test database

Is this some kind of bug?

**Edit**:

- I meant development database. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your `db/schema.rb` what you have there. The rake tasks db:test:prepare (and db:test:load) just recreate the database from your schema file, which can become inconsistent with the schema_migrations table in certain cases (when you run migration and then change it during development).

If you have id defined as an INT in your schema and you have no pending migrations in your dev environment then you need to rerun your migration with `rake db:migrate:redo`.

Answer (score 0):

You specifically say **production database**, so that makes me wonder if you ran the migrations in your development environment as well. Imho `rake db:test:prepare` creates a copy of your development database, so make you sure all your migrations have also run in development (we had a problem with that on our build machine, where there was no development database). To be sure that your test-database is created for the current schema, you could also use

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset
```

This will drop and recreate the database using the `schema.rb` file.

Comment: Sorry. I meant development database. The problem is that `schema.rb` contains int `id`, and only migrations have `change_column` that change id->varchar.